# Linq to Entities EF4

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have a Groups domain model with `name`,`desc` and collection of `users`(belonging to the group)

I am trying to get all groups that a particular user belongs to. This is my LinQ statement:

```
var results = from p in AuthorizationService.UnitOfWork.Groups.FindAll()
                          where
                              (p.Users != null && p.Users.Select(u => u.Id).Contains(CurrentUser.Id))
                          select p.Name;
```

I get the following error when i try to execute the query

```
Cannot compare elements of type 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1'. Only primitive types (such as Int32, String, and Guid) and entity types are supported.
```

Any help is appreciated.Thanks!

Comment: Why not drop that last Contains clause and wrap that into your select?

Comment: rig, can you show me how the query would look like?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Remove the null testing for Users object, anyway it's lazy loaded, is your Users virtual? if it is, it is lazy-loaded, it's ok to remove the null testing then

```
var results = 
from p in AuthorizationService.UnitOfWork.Groups.FindAll() 
where 
     p.Users.Any(u => u.Id == CurrentUser.Id)
select p.Name;
```

Comment: It's ok to remove the null testing. Linq to Entities (not Linq to objects) we are writing are just being translated to string. EF is not so smart about object comparison. An example, this Linq is allowed in NHibernate: `from p in person where p != null`, it automatically gets translated `select * from person where p.Id is not null`, while EF Linq demand you compare things down to their primitive type, so you have to write `from p in person where p.Id != null`

Answer (score 0):

Can't you go the opposite way?

```
var results = AuthorizationService.UnitOfWork.Users.Include("Groups").First(u => u.ID == CurrentUser.Id).Select(u => u.Groups);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks anton, but i am not allowed to change the existing model.